# How do I import properties for polygons from my geojson file

Tags: json, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I am having issues importing properties from my geojson file.
I am very new, and trying to learn the best I can but I've been stumped on this for a while.

I have a geojson with about 50~ polygons that all have unique styling. I can import the polygons no problem into my leaflet map however the style properties do not transfer over.

I have tried various methods to try and import the properties and apply them. None of which have worked so far.

Here is my latest attempt at importing my GeoJSON and applying the proper styles for each polygon.

```
var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX("boundaries.geojson", {
style: function (feature){
return{
    stroke: 'feature.properties.stroke', 
    strokeWidth: 'feature.properties.stroke-width', 
    strokeOpacity: 'feature.properties.stroke-opacity',
    fill: 'feature.properties.fill', 
    fillOpacity: 'feature.properties.fill-opacity',  
    name: 'feature.properties.name', 
};
}});
```

No error messages in my console. The polygons will load with the default blue borders and fill when I exclude my attempt at pulling the styles from the GeoJSON file.

Comment: Try using the values without the quotes, i.e. `stroke: feature.properties.stroke` in stead of stroke: 'feature.properties.stroke'.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually figured it out.

```
$.getJSON('boundaries.geojson', function (bound) {
                    var zonelayer = L.geoJson(bound, {
                        style: function (feature) {
                            return {
                        weight: feature.properties.strokewidth, 
                        color: feature.properties.strokecolor,
                        strokeOpacity: feature.properties.strokeopacity, 
                        fillColor: feature.properties.fill, 
                        fillOpacity: feature.properties.fillopacity};
                        },
                    }).addTo(map);
            });
```